# Универсальный метод скриншота окна

Tags: c#, winapi, graphics, usercontrol, controls

Нашел здесь отличное решения для создания скриншотов по дескриптору окна. Я его немного подредактировал под свои нужды, получилось следующее:

```
using (var image = new Bitmap(rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top))
{
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        var hdcBitmap = graphics.GetHdc();
        WinAPI.PrintWindow(Handle, hdcBitmap, 0);
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
    }
    bmp = new Bitmap(image);
}
```

WinAPI - просто класс-обертка extern функций.
Но, если я не ошибаюсь, контролы тоже являются окнами и имеют свой Handle. Этот метод не может сделать снимок контрола. Да, я знаю про DrawToBitmap, но как переписать этот метод, чтобы он работал в обоих случаях, ведь может быть передан дескриптор абсолютно любого окна.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать [это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Но ведь тогда я получу саму форму. Ладно, если бы можно было определить, с чем имею дело - формой или контролом. В случае контрола просто бы вырезал из скриншота Rectangle контрола, но универсального решения я не вижу. Хотя... можно всегда вырезать рект нужного контрола от скриншота родителя, с формой тоже сработает, вот только от рабочего стола не получится взять скриншот же. А с GetDesktopWindow у меня никогда не получилось работать.

Comment: Пардон не сразу понял суть вопроса. Для определения что хэндл является дочерним есть функция [IsChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633524(v=vs.85).aspx). Вы в принципе правильно рассуждаете. Нужно достаточно написать функцию которая будет делать скрин всего родительского окна и вырезать из него прямоугольник. А прямоугольником будет либо дочерний контрол либо вся область главного окна. IMHO это довольно универсальное решение.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, и отпишусь по факту!